# C++ problem with dlopen(), how to correct open it?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I have try to open .so

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void *handle;
    handle = dlopen("test.so",RTLD_LAZY );

    return 0;
}
```

compile by

```bash
g++ -ldl -o untitled5 main.cpp
```

and have such problem :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQsDBYl.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Put `-ldl` as the last argument (after `main.cpp`) - `g++ -o untitled5 main.cpp -ldl`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Can you help with setting this in CMake?

Comment: I don't really know CMake, but there's `target_link_library` function for that. And I guess it should be after `add_executable`.